# Plotting a groupby function with respect to date

Tags: python, pandas, spyder

[image: Output of groupby function]

I am planning to plot a scatter plot, between the `groupby` function and date attribute. But I couldn't plot. Output of the `groupby` function is in the attachment.

[Data file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=19w_DgVDoqYHUX1xHOdzsHAdNSNjyt2Wz)

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


D1 = pd.ExcelFile("C:/Users/kdandebo/Desktop/Models/Python excercise/Capstone/ProdData.xlsx")
df=D1.parse("Calculations")
print(df.info())
print(df.columns)

F = df.head(10)
Z = F.groupby(['Date','Produce Name','Actual Boxes'])['Produce Name'].count()
print(Z)

plt.scatter(Z,Z['Date'])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide a sample data that we can reproduce, instead of images.

Comment: Added the data file

Answer (score 0):

I tried to get the group by data and here it is and I am guessing you are trying to plot Date and the last column. Is that correct ?

Date       Produce Name   Actual Boxes
2017-05-18  Basil          2.50            1
                           3.00            1
2017-05-22  Butterhead S.  2.00            1
            Jerico         1.50            1
            RO Salanova    1.00            1
            Romaine        1.50            1
            Salanova GO    2.30            1
            Sweet Crisp    2.00            1
2017-05-30  Romaine        3.00            1
            Salanova GO    0.66            1

Comment: No Kirsh.. from the grouby data which you have shown above, I am trying to plot date and product name corresponding to its boxes

Comment: do  u mean the product name counts on the x axis and the date on the y axis ?

Comment: Yes krish , thats what i mean

Comment: But you are getting multiple values for each date because of the other group by columns. So for example if u see there are 2 values for 30/5/2017 because there is Romaine and Salanova each for 1 amount. So are u wanting to plot each of these for 30/5/2017 are the total count of 2 ?